# Haystack's SearchQuerySet().filter not doing anything (Whoosh 2.4.1, Django-haystack 1.2.7)

Tags: django, django-haystack, whoosh

**views.py** (relevant part)

```
srch = request.GET.get('search', "") 
sqs = SearchQuerySet().filter(has_title=True)
clean_query = sqs.query.clean(srch)
results = sqs.raw_search(clean_query)
```

**search_indexes.py**

```
from haystack.indexes import *
from haystack import site
from myproject.myapp.models import Person

class PersonIndex(SearchIndex):
    text = CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    name = CharField(model_attr='name')    
    has_title = BooleanField(model_attr='has_title')

site.register(Person, PersonIndex)
```

**models.py**

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50) 
    has_title = models.BooleanField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % self.name
```

When searching, I get my results out of the complete model instead of only those entries were `has_title` is `True`. I also ran `python manage.py rebuild_index` after applying the filter. Why does the filter not work?

I am using `Whoosh 2.4.1`, `Django-haystack 1.2.7` and `Django 1.4`.

If someone could just confirm that they can successfully use `SearchQuerySet().filter` with `Whoosh 2.4` and `Django-haystack 1.2.7` this would already be a big help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that `raw_search(clean_query)` just returns every item in `sqs` again (don't know why), using `filter(content=clean_query)` instead gets the expected result.

```
srch = request.GET.get('search', "") 
sqs = SearchQuerySet().filter(has_title=True)
clean_query = sqs.query.clean(srch)
result = sqs.filter(content=clean_query)
```