# Django-Haystack: How to limit search within entries that have a specific value for a given field?

Tags: django, search, django-haystack

Say I have a model `Person` for which there is a `PersonIndex` class in `search_indexes.py` that makes all fields of it searchable. **How can I make a search within only those entries where say the `has_title` field is `True`**?

**I tried the following, but it just searches among all entries**, not just the ones where `has_title` is `True`:

```
srch = request.GET.get('search', "") 
sqs = SearchQuerySet().filter(has_title=True)
clean_query = sqs.query.clean(srch)
results = sqs.raw_search(clean_query)
```

I am using `Whoosh 2.4.1`, `Django-haystack 1.2.7` and `Django 1.4`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `filter(content=clean_query)` instead of `raw_search(clean_query)`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14216207/haystacks-searchqueryset-filter-not-doing-anything-whoosh-2-4-1-django-hays/14415290#14415290) for more details.